# t.onAdd is not a function

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am getting an error when using `map.addLayer` or `marker.addTo(map)` it gives

> t.onAdd is not a function

I believe either I am missing any library or what.
please help me out to get rid of this problem.
**latLongShipArray** contains lat/long values

```
var array = [];  // create an global array

for (var i = 0; i < latLongShipArray.length - 1; i++) {  //latLongShipArray consists lat/long values

    if (shipCoordinateArray[i]["Type"][0] == 1) { // condition to add marker ,shipCoordinateArray have some conditions
        marker = new L.marker(latLongShipArray[i], { //add lat/long in new marker
            icon: shipIConBigger
        });
        //marker.addTo(map);
        //map.addLayer(marker);
        marker.on('click', onMarkerPointClick);
    }
    else {   //condition to add marker
        marker = new L.marker(latLongShipArray[i], { // add lat/long in new marker
            icon: shipIConSmaller
        });
        //marker.addTo(map);
        //map.addLayer(marker);
        marker.on('click', onMarkerPointClick);  //click event
    }
    array.push(marker);   //push marker to array
}
var shipCoordinateMarker = L.layerGroup([array]);  // add a layergroup
//shipCoordinateMarker.addTo(map);
map.addLayer(shipCoordinateMarker);  // add marker array to map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize your Layer Group with an array of array of Markers:

```js
var shipCoordinateMarker = L.layerGroup([array]);  // add a layergroup
```

Should be simply:

```js
var shipCoordinateMarker = L.layerGroup(array);  // add a layergroup
```

since `array` is already an Array of Markers.

Furthermore, the error you report is probably when using Leaflet version < 1.0.0. When using Leaflet version 1.0.0+, the exact error message due to this mistake should be different. Therefore you should probably upgrade your version.

Comment: okay but the main problem is that I have an array of approx 30k markers and when they are adding that much markers in one go the page gets unresponsive

Comment: Sounds to me like a totally different issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015854/large-dataset-of-markers-or-dots-in-leaflet as a starting point. Consider a heat map or clustering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043791/plotting-140k-points-in-leafletjs Feel free to open a new question if you need further help.

Comment: thanx that's what i want

Answer (score 0):

The command for adding a feature/layer group to the map is *group.addTo(map);*

In your case:

```
shipCoordinateMarker.addTo(map);
```

Comment: still it shows same error

Comment: Try to remove the *new* when creating the marker.

Comment: actually, i have around 30k markers and I want to add it on a map but when I am adding it like that the page gets unresponsive because it takes time.

Comment: That is quite a lot for Leaflet to handle, indeed... you could look into clustering. Maybe you can try it with just a few markers to see if the issue is related to the number of markers (most likely not) or something else.

Comment: yeah i had tried with least number of markers it works fine but if it goes beyond around 10k then pages gets unresponsive